# Textfield moves when tapping Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

I have a problem that I never had before.
I have a ViewController with a tableView on full screen. Constraints 0,0,0,0 to safe area.

In a header view I have some imageviews and labels - the height of the is dynamic , the cells (1 prototype ) are used for comments. the cells have dynamic height, too. In a footer I have a textfield and a send button.

When I click the textfield the keyboard comes up and I can see what I'm typing - great! But only great if I'm not using the iPhone Keyboard. Typing on iMac external keyboard is fine - typing on the simulators keyboard moves my footer view within the send button and the textfield to bottom of view. When pressing CMD + K Keyboard disappears and I can see what I was typing.

Any ideas?

One other note: when scrolling down the header is layered under the clock & battery-icon. how to prevent that?

Kind regards and thanks for help in advance.

iOS -> 15.2 on iPhone 11 Simulator
Xcode 14.2
using InterfaceBuilder

EDIT: SCREENSHOTS

1. [top of view controller normal / unscrolled. background of clock and battery icons etc is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEtcu.jpg)
2. [bottom end of view controller. the textfield and the send button are in a footer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMgBO.jpg)
3. [when clicking into textfield keyboard appears but at top of view controller the image is under the clock and battery icon - it should be like users scrolls normal as in screenshot before was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3UqN.jpg)
4. [tapping keys on external iMac keyboard is normal - the footer with textfield and button stays on top of keyboard but when tapping keys of simulator keyboard the footer goes back to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6wxk.jpg)
5. [after pressing CMD + K on iMac or tapping outside the keyboard view will endEditing and keyboard will disappear and user can see the written text in textfield and is able to send comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0GLu.jpg)

Comment: Why not use a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController with a UITableView added to it?

Comment: Before i was using that setup i had a scrollView within 10 or more stackviews. I‘m not sure how many work it would be to setup everything to a tableviewcontroller … i have many segues to it and from it 

Comment: pls Attach some screenshot to help you understand your question more

Comment: @AhmedMohiy i have edited the question and added screenshots. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to read this guid carefully from apple [Adjusting Your Layout with Keyboard Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/adjusting_your_layout_with_keyboard_layout_guide)

i added a view underneath the status bar and the navigation bar has the same color as the navigation bar then the main view will slide underneath  that view when the keyboard ins open here is the sample code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        navigationItem.title = "Navigation bar"

        
        let statusBarView = UIView()
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = .black
        statusBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(statusBarView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            statusBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            statusBarView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            statusBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            statusBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        ])
        
        let mainView = UIView()
        mainView.backgroundColor = .red
        mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(mainView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusBarView.bottomAnchor),
            mainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            mainView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        ])
        
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.backgroundColor = .black
        textField.placeholder = "TextField"
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainView.addSubview(textField)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor),
            textField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            textField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
        ])
        
        
    }


}
```

you can create a sample code and test the code but make sure to embed your viewController in a navigationController in your storyboard